# Comparing more than one variable to value(s) - Python

Tags: python, variables, integer, compare

I am solving a chess problem that demands using only basic math and comparison operators. I need the program to work only within a 8x8 chess board.
I have two variables (A, B) - both should be >=1 and <=8 for the program to work. I've tried these code options:

```
1 <= A, B <= 8
1 <= (A, B) <= 8
1 <= (A and B) <= 8
```

I've also tried assigning both A and B to a third variable - C and then comparing the variable C:

```
1 <= C <= 8
```

All of them do not work. **Is there a way to do this in Python** (Using basic math and comparison operators) **without having to compare every variable separately?**

Comment: The way operators work won't allow for something using the syntax you are trying to use. You could do something like `all(1 <= n <= 8 for n in (a,b))` but not sure if that's any simpler than just using two comparisons.

Comment: What you want is not directly achievable in python, directly or indirectly you have to put  the separate conditions.

Comment: You'll have to make all distinct comparisons `(A >= 1) & (A <= 8) & (B >= 1) & (B <= 8)`

Comment: @SurajShourie `&` is a bitwise "and" in Python. My solution would be `(1 <= A <= 8) and (1 <= B <= 8)`.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of different ways to do this in python off the top of my head.

using pythons [range command](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#ranges) `A in range(1,9) and B in range (1,9)` works if they are both integers (Keep in mind its inclusive of first number, not inclusive of last)

I would honestly just write a function that takes a list of values and a min/max number.

```
def in_range(list_values, minimum_value, maximum_value):
    for num in list_values:
        if num < minimum_value or num > maximum_value:
             return False
        return True

print(in_range( [A,B], 1, 8)
```

*edit* Just re-read the question, I'd still recomend a function call but you could probably just do

```
 def in_range(A,B):
     return A in range (0,9) and B in range(0,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with comparing every variable separately when the comparison involves only 2 variables (and always only 2 variables since they represent a coordinate on a chess board).

That said, you can use `8 >= A >= 1 <= B <= 8` if for some reason you must keep the expression a single chained comparison.